# Android Java : Turn screen Off

Tags: java, android, permissions, screen

I am making an application that turn the screen ON and OFF with the proximity sensor.
The proximity code is finished, but i got trouble using the screen controls.

I have read that I should use,

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);
```

For that, I need to grant special permissions in order to make it works, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Also, I have read about changing screen brightness

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
            params.screenBrightness = 0;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But this way only turn the screen off on my application; it doesn't work if my application is running in background.

I have also read about using Wakelock (i use them to wake my phone from screen-off), but when

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

But when I do that, nothing happens.

Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643907/putting-the-system-to-sleep-on-android

Comment: Thank's, but it seems the problem has neither been resolved there

Comment: @Sit: How did you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your App the right permissions to do that:

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />` to your Manifest inside the `<manifest>` Tag

If you want to keep your Screen on use this, as suggested by Dianne Hackborn on Google Plus:
[KeepScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've put that permission in the manifest, but since it's a level 2 permission, we need to have a specific permission (System) in order to use it. That's what i've called "Special permissions", sorry i've explained it in a very bad way.