# Set Screen off on click home button

Tags: android, screen

I would like to set screen off on press HOME_BUTTON.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        System.out.println("home button");
        finish();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                params.screenBrightness = 0;
                getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Can any one help me 
thank you

Comment: So what have you tried beside catching the home key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294917/android-java-turn-screen-off

Comment: @khouloudmejdoub you should add that code to your question and not as a unreadable comment...

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i get the solution

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (PreferenceHelper.getScreenLock(Recognition.this)) {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.screenBrightness = 1;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (PreferenceHelper.getScreenLock(Recognition.this)) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.screenBrightness = 0;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
    System.out.println("home button");
    DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mDPM.lockNow();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

This will lock your screen on the press of home button.

Comment: when i add this code this Error appear:Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10004 for policy #3